# Instagram iOS Plugin for Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: plugins, cordova, instagram

Has anyone used the Instagram Plugin for Cordova/Phonegap (https://github.com/vstirbu/InstagramPlugin) and have a sample implementation they would be willing to share with me?

Comment: Are you having specific problems integrating the plugin with your app, or are you just looking to "try it out?"

Comment: Can you tell me what specific problem have you encountered with the plugin?

Comment: I have implemented above plugin but I found one issue this plugin not redirect back to phonegap app after sharing on instagram. Please help me on this.

Comment: a sample application of this plugin is available [here](https://github.com/vstirbu/instagramplugin-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried in my phonegap application steps as below,

Pre requisite : Instagram App installed in your device.

if you have installed phonegap using node js then

its simple to add plugin to app

1. add plugin : cordova plugins add https://github.com/vstirbu/InstagramPlugin
2. add  to your index.html page.
3. you can test instagram installed or not using below code,

   Instagram.isInstalled(function (err, installed) {
       if (installed) {
           console.log("Instagram is installed");
       } else {
           console.log("Instagram is not installed");
       }
      });
4. then share your image (you need to pass base64 or canvas id)

   Instagram.share(canvas_id or base64, function (err) {
                       if (err) {
                       alert("not shared");
                       } else {
                       alert("shared");
                       }
                       });
5. it open device default sharing popup then select instagram to share and that it.

Note : After sharing on instagram not redirect to phonegap app back this is the major issue with it.

Comment: I'm using this <canvas id="insta" onclick="app.share();">
but don't open the image, just a black view.. Could you tel me how can i do it?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6jqpxtnlahx04n/IMG_2154.PNG?dl=0
Thanks